# Time reversal in Robertson's chemical reaction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, applications, chemistry

I am studying the behavior of the Robertson chemical reaction,

$$\begin{array}{rl} \dot{x} &= -0.04 x + 10^4 y z\\ \dot{y} &= 0.04 x - 10^4 y z - 3 \times 10^7 y^2\\ \dot{z} &= 3 \times 10^7 y^2\end{array}$$

(source: [Wikipedia on stiff equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation)).

I have noticed that numerical schemes can integrate this equation forwards in time but not backwards; that is, for a given initial condition $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, integrating forward to $t = t_1$ and then reversing the integration back to $t = t_0$ yields a solution not equal to the initial condition.

I am wondering about the mathematical reason for this, and if there is any remedy. Is this a feature of all stiff equations? Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

**More detail:** I chose the initial condition $(3, 1, 2)$ as an example, but I have observed this effect with other initial conditions as well. Let $t_0 = 0$ and $t_1 = 1$. For the first integration:

$t = 1$, $(x, y, z) = (3.00609, 4.00023 \times 10^{-6}, 2.99391)$

And for the reverse integration:

$t = 0$, $(x, y, z) = ( 3.00657, 4.00151 \times 10^{-6}, 2.99343 )$

I use the BDF integration method and have tried multiple implementations; all of the results are consistent with each other.

Comment: "numerical schemes can integrate this equation forwards in time but not backwards" Any evidence supporting this statement?

Comment: @Did, perhaps I should have been more clear. Numerical schemes _can_ integrate this backwards, but they arrive at the wrong answer. I can't recover the initial condition.

Comment: Then same question about "but they arrive at the wrong answer".

Comment: @Did, suppose we assume some initial condition $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and integrate forward from $t = t_0$ to $t = t_1$. Then, taking that answer, integrate backwards from $t = t_1$ to $t = t_0$. The answer the integrator finds at the end of this procedure is significantly different from $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

Comment: Yes, you already say that in the question, but we still have zero amount of evidence, or even, of information, about this startling statement. Did you *observe* this effect numerically? Then show the numerics.

Comment: @Did, I updated the question. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: About how big are the step sizes here? It is not all that surprising to see that your initial condition and your forward-backward integration are not quite the same. In particular, if your step sizes are not very small, the error in $x$ seems reasonable. The real problem is that error in $y$ (and by mass conservation in $z$ too): why does $y$ become so small going forward in time but then does not become of order $1$ again going backward in time?

Comment: @Ian, the implementations I tried pick their own stepsizes, so I'm not sure exactly what they were. The initial stepsize tried was $10^{-12}$ in this example. As for the error in $y$... that's why I'm here :)

Comment: Well, if you actually look at the *dynamics* I think you see the problem: the $y,z$ dynamics are extremely stiff so that $y$ is close to zero almost immediately. Thus the backward in time dynamics need to resolve the reverse effect: $y$ gets just a little bit bigger and then explodes back up to $1$ somehow. That is not that surprising to be a problem seeing as the positive contribution to $\dot{y}$ is $y$ times something.

Comment: You can see the step sizes in, say, Matlab by calculating $t$ in the solver, by the way.

Comment: @Ian I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Related: http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/vodef90web/problems/demosnodislin/Single/DemoRobertson/demorobertson.pdf                                                            Also:https://books.google.com/books?id=NGvrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=robertson+reaction+differential+equation&source=bl&ots=ckCRhTgdNH&sig=lE7KTXvAvTh6p5J_wEdDwWuGSLU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjg8-hr-HVAhXKr1QKHcKBBdUQ6AEIYzAJ#v=onepage&q=robertson%20reaction%20differential%20equation&f=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in the system you have written down is that the $y,z$ dynamics, especially the $y$ dynamics, are stiff, meaning that they demonstrate multiple time scales. At the beginning $y$ is rapidly converted into $z$, then the process mostly settles down. In the backward in time dynamics the integrator never sees $y$ start to get significantly larger and so it does not refine the step sizes to become small enough to resolve the transient effect.

This problem is apparently a benchmark for integrators for stiff ODEs, so you should not expect an "easy" fix to correct the problem.

Comment: Another problem with the integration seems to be that, once the system reaches a steady state, numerical error makes it virtually impossible to reverse the time coordinate. Once $x, y, z$ become "constant" in time (due to roundoff error?), reversing time causes the system to explode back up to the initial condition too quickly, since the system has no explicit dependence on $t$. I don't know if there is a term for that, or if it falls into the category of stiffness.

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars The true dynamics slow down but do not stop in the long run. The reversed numerical dynamics only see this slow behavior. This is related to stiffness: it is a problem of the initial decay being too fast to be re-detected upon time reversal. (Also the problem is with truncation error, not roundoff error.)